# Why can't I create an int* pointer to an enum variable whose base type is int?

Tags: c++, pointers, enums

I have this:

```
enum GameObjectType : int
{
    GameObjectType_STATIC          = 0,
    GameObjectType_LOOTABLE        = 1,
    GameObjectType_LANDMARK        = 2,
    GameObjectType_PORTAL          = 3,
    GameObjectType_QUEST           = 4,
    GameObjectType_LOOTABLE_BOX    = 5,
};

GameObjectType mytype = GameObjectType_LANDMARK;
```

However this is invalid:

```
int* myPtr = &mytype;
```

Why is that and is there any way to have int pointer to enum ?

Comment: Why do you want one?

Comment: You could `reinterpret_cast` the pointer, but dereferencing the resulting pointer would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is bad thing.

Comment: @PaulSanders because of `int* current_item` in https://gist.github.com/Armmegon/53d0452eedfb65d5c84f73c042ec398e

Comment: Rethink the name of your _variable_ that carries _a value_ and then `mytype` will fall out of grace promptly.

Comment: A `GameObjectType` is not an `int`. If your function says that it wants a `int*`, then you shouldn't try to pass it a pointer to a `GameObjectType`. If you want to pass a pointer to a `GameObjectType` to your function, then it should accept a `GameObjectType*`, not an `int*`. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: `struct GameObjectType { enum { xstatic, lootable, landmark, portal, quest, lootable_box }; int got_int; };` and then `int* myPtr = &got.got_int;`.

Comment: @Venelin Note that C++23 has [`std::to_underlying()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_underlying) to convert an `enum` value to its underlying type. But that won't help as it returns a copy of the value, you still can't get a pointer to the `enum` itself. The best you can do is this: `int value = std::to_underlying(mytype); int* myPtr = &value;` Which is basically this in earlier versions: `int value = static_cast<int>(mytype); int* myPtr = &value;`

Comment: Usually when someone asks for a pointer to an `int` it's because they want to change the value inside the function (not a good thing to do if the value's not really an `int`) or they're actually expecting an array of `int`.

Comment: @Venelin On a side note: your `enum` values are a bit wordy, why are you not using a *scoped* `enum` instead? `enum class GameObjectType : int { STATIC, LOOTABLE, LANDMARK, PORTAL, QUEST, LOOTABLE_BOX }; GameObjectType mytype = GameObjectType::LANDMARK;`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Is it undefined behavior to reinterpret_cast to actual underlying type?

Comment: Why would you want a pointer to an integer from an enum value? If you want to change it, then use a reference to enumeration type : `GameObjectType &type`. If you need to convert it to/from int do it as close as possible to where you need an integer. As mentionned by Remy, you should prefer enum class too.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that

Because `GameObjectType` and `int` are different types.

> is there any way to have int pointer to enum ?

No (assuming you want the pointer to be dereferencible).

You could define a "fancy pointer" class that internally points to such enum, but whose indirection operator returns an `int`.

Comment: `enum GameObjectType : int {...}` *looks like* it might be a type of inheritance (i.e. declaring `GameObjectType` to be a subclass of `int`), but it isn't.